# How to add backdrop/blur effect with SVG in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uiblureffect

I have following UI requirement in react native.

[image]

I have tried to make the red box portion as it is. However could not find the optimal solution.
I have tried with .svg image however, blur effect using `feGaussianBlur` is not achievable in react native due to DOM.

If anybody can suggest a way to make curve with View

Or

A way to blur sag image creating similar effect. Will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your question . This is not clear

Comment: In react-native you can blur an image with this 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#blurradius. Please clarify your question